# In Ember, how do I create a component that reacts to the action of another component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a `button-icon` component that, when hovered over, will send a `hoverIn` and `hoverOut` action (example code so please forgive any errors):

> app/components/button-icon/component.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    // hover in
    this.$().hover(function() {
      this.sendAction('hoverIn');
    ,
    // hover out
    function() {
      this.sendAction('hoverOut');
    }
  },

  // more code here to handle other stuff
});
```

> app/components/button-icon/template.hbs:

```
<button>{{yield}}</button>
```

I also have a `button-tooltip` component that should be displayed when the button is hovered over:

> app/components/button-tooltip/component.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    // some code here to handle positioning
});
```

> app/components/button-tooltip/template.hbs:

```
<div>{{yield}}</div>
```

In my template, I'd like to use both like so:

> app/index/template.hbs:

```
{{#button-icon}}
  <div>Cat</div>
  {{#button-tooltip}}<img src="cat.png">{{/button-tooltip}}
{{/button-icon}}

{{#button-icon}}
  <div>Dog</div>
  {{#button-tooltip}}<img src="dog.png">{{/button-tooltip}}
{{/button-icon}}

{{#button-icon}}
  <div>Rat</div>
  {{#button-tooltip}}Nobody wants to see a picture of a rat!{{/button-tooltip}}
{{/button-icon}}
```

How do I get the `button-icon` to communicate with the `button-tooltip` so that the tooltip is shown when the icon is hovered over? If I only had one button, I can bind both the button and tooltip to a property on the controller, but I have a variable list of them to display. I can also wrap both components in another component (called `button-with-tooltip` or something), but this seems like it's starting to get into component-ception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty complicated to set such kind of interactions when you have that templates. Your components are fully independent, but they should have a parent-child connection, since they are actually the parent and a child.

A more suitable approach for me is below.

> app/index/template.hbs

```
{{#buttons-list buttons=property_with_a_correct_list_from_the_index_controller}}
```

> app/components/button-list/template.hbs

```
{{#each button in buttons}}
  {{#button-icon data=button}}
{{/each}}
```

> app/components/button-icon/template.hbs

```
<div>{{data.title}}</div>
{{#button-tooltip data=data.tooltip}}
```

> app/components/button-icon/component.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'button',

  ...

});
```

> app/components/button-tooltip/template.hbs:

```
{{#if isPicture}}
  <img src={{data.image}} />
{{else}}
  {{data.text}}
{{/if}}
```

> app/components/button-tooltip/component.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'div'
  isPicture: function() {
    this.get('data.type') == 'image'
  }.property('data.type')
});
```

And the `property_with_a_correct_list_from_the_index_controller` should look like this

```
[
  {title: 'Cat', tooltip: {isPicture: true, image: 'cat.png'}},
  {title: 'Dog', tooltip: {isPicture: true, image: 'dog.png'}},
  {title: 'Rat', tooltip: {isPicture: false, text: 'Nobody wants to see a picture of a rat!'}}
]
```

Let's review it:

- I moved edged tags in the components to the controllers in a `tagName` property
- A content of a tooltip now directed by the tooltip itself, not by the parent icon component
- Now a tooltip and an icon have clear relationship, so the icon finally *has* any reasonable way to control it

For now let's determine your high-level requirement for the sample:

- User should see a tooltip when hovers an icon.
- User shouldn't see a tooltip when leaved an icon.

As you can see the icon component totally controls the tooltip visibility. In this case I'd consider an approach with conditional template. For example:

> app/components/button-icon/component.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'button',
  showTooltip: false,

  didInsertElement: function() {
    self = this // this will be redefined inside of hover function
    // hover in
    this.$().hover(function() {
      self.set('showTooltip', true);
    ,
    // hover out
    function() {
      self.set('showTooltip', false);
    }
  },

  // more code here to handle other stuff
});
```

> app/components/button-icon/template.hbs

```
<div>{{data.title}}</div>
{{#if showTooltip}}
  {{#button-tooltip data=data.tooltip}}
{{/if}}
```

As you can see, your sample is rewritten in a more clear way, where you can see a approach to control tooltip visibility. I'd recommend to use such approach only in case when you need to control the tooltip visibility.

Back to

> more code here to handle other stuff

For this I would recommend to not discard your approach with binding of a property. Just create a property with a required state in the `button-icon` component and make a corresponding computed property in the `button-tooltip` component, which will be listening for changes in the property.

Example:

> app/components/button-icon/component.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'button',
  tooltipProps: [],

  didInsertElement: function() {
    self = this // this will be redefined inside of hover function
    // hover in
    this.$().hover(function() { 
      self.get('tooltipProps').addObject('showIt');
    , function() { // hover out
      self.get('tooltipProps').removeObject('showIt');
    });
    this.$().on('click', function() {
      self.get('tooltipProps').addObject('makeitRed');
    });
  },

  // more code here to handle other stuff
});
```

> app/components/button-icon/template.hbs

```
<div>{{data.title}}</div>
{{#button-tooltip data=data.tooltip props=tooltipProps}
```

> app/components/button-tooltip/component.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'div'
  isPicture: function() {
    this.get('data.type') == 'image'
  }.property('data.type'),

  onPropsChange: function() {
    if (this.get('props.makeItRed')) {
      // make it actually red directly by the own component code
    }
  }.observe('props') // an observer because you need to do actions here, if you want to change the internal state use a computed property
});
```

P.S. But the first approach I like more %)

Answer (score 0):

Once you are using a version of ember that supports yielding values in a component, I think this is 1.10.0, you can do the following, which is very intuitive.

```
{{#button-icon as |active|}}
  <div>Cat</div>

  {{#button-tooltip active=active}}
    <img src="cat.png">
  {{/button-tooltip}}
{{/button-icon}}
```

And in your `button-icon` component instead of sending an action up, you would set a value e.g. `isActive`, and send that down.

```
<button>{{yield isActive}}</button>
```

The idea is actions up, data down.